# At Node js server when validation job runs which takes half an hour then during that period entire application stopped working

Tags: node.js

I am using MEAN stack to develop my application. My server has three clients app 1. iOS App 2. Android App and 3. Browser based App. All app is served from single server. I am facing problem when I run some long data processing job. This job takes half an hour to finish one processing. Due to single thread modal of Nodejs, when this job starts running then during that half an hour all of the three app stopped working becuase server doesn't respond on timelimit. Following is my code for job.

```
1. API to invoke this processing 
//API to validate all possible combinations
app.get('/api/validateworkouts/:clubid',  SecurityService.isRestAPIRequestSecure, workoutValidateService.validateGeneratedWorkouts);
2. Following is code for validateGeneratedWorkouts function
module.exports = {
// Test generated workouts for all users and send email to admin team
    validateGeneratedWorkouts: function (req, res) {
        var clubid = req.params.clubid;
        //update club status as inprogress in database
        module.exports.updateClubWorkoutTestStatusAsInprogress(clubid, function () {
            //Get user data from database
            var query = {};
            query.username = "user@validate.com";
            documentOperationModule.getDocumentByQuery(query, constants.USER_COLLECTION, function (err, users) {
                if (!err && !Utilities.isEmptyList(users)) {
                    //Get all goals data from database
                    query = {};
                    documentOperationModule.getDocumentByQuery(query, constants.GOAL_COLLECTION, function (err, goals) {
                        if (!err && !Utilities.isEmptyList(goals)) {
                            //Get all scheduleconfigfrequencies
                            query = {};
                            documentOperationModule.getDocumentByQuery(query, constants.SCHEDULE_CONFIG_FREQUENCIES_COLLECTION, function (err, scheduleconfigfrequencies) {
                                if (!err && !Utilities.isEmptyList(scheduleconfigfrequencies)) {
                                    //Get all genders
                                    query = {};
                                    documentOperationModule.getDocumentByQuery(query, constants.GENDERS_COLLECTION, function (err, genders) {
                                        if (!err && !Utilities.isEmptyList(genders)) {
                                            //Get all experiences
                                            query = {};
                                            documentOperationModule.getDocumentByQuery(query, constants.EXPERIENCES_COLLECTION, function (err, experiences) {
                                                if (!err && !Utilities.isEmptyList(experiences)) {

                                                    //Get all durationpreferences
                                                    query = {};
                                                    documentOperationModule.getDocumentByQuery(query, constants.DURATION_PREFERENCES_COLLECTION, function (err, durationpreferences) {
                                                        if (!err && !Utilities.isEmptyList(durationpreferences)) {
                                                            //Get all clubs
                                                            query = {};
                                                            documentOperationModule.getDocumentByQuery(query, constants.CLUB_COLLECTION, function (err, clubs) {
                                                                if (!err && !Utilities.isEmptyList(clubs)) {
                                                                    var workoutRequestList = [];
                                                                    //prepare workout request for each combinations                                                                                         //loop in each users
                                                                    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                                                                        //loop in each goals
                                                                        for (var j = 0; j < goals.length; j++) {
                                                                            //loop in each scheduleconfigfrequencies
                                                                            for (var k = 0; k < scheduleconfigfrequencies.length; k++) {
                                                                                //loop in each genders
                                                                                for (var l = 0; l < genders.length; l++) {
                                                                                    //loop in each experiences
                                                                                    for (var m = 0; m < experiences.length; m++) {
                                                                                        //loop in each durationpreferences
                                                                                        for (var n = 0; n < durationpreferences.length; n++) {
                                                                                            var userid = users[i].userid;
                                                                                            var goalid = goals[j].goalid;
                                                                                            var gender = genders[l].genderid;
                                                                                            var experience = experiences[m].experienceid;
                                                                                            var durationpreference = durationpreferences[n].durationpreferenceid;
                                                                                            var frequency = scheduleconfigfrequencies[k].scheduleconfigfrequencyid;
                                                                                            //loop in for each possible workout sequence based on frequency
                                                                                            for (var nextworkoutseq = 0; nextworkoutseq < frequency; nextworkoutseq++) {
                                                                                                        //Get list of workout request object
                                                                                                        var workoutRequest = {};
                                                                                                        workoutRequest.url = workoutURL;
                                                                                                        workoutRequest.userid = userid;
                                                                                                        workoutRequest.clubid = clubid;
                                                                                                        workoutRequest.goalid = goalid;
                                                                                                        workoutRequest.gender = gender;
                                                                                                        workoutRequest.experience = experience;
                                                                                                        workoutRequest.durationpreference = durationpreference;
                                                                                                        workoutRequest.frequency = frequency;
                                                                                                        workoutRequest.nextworkoutseq = nextworkoutseq;
                                                                                                        //Add into list
                                                                                                        workoutRequestList.push(workoutRequest);
                                                                                            }

                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                    //Generate workout and add into response if it fails
                                                                    var failedWorkoutRequestsList = [];
                                                                    //call getFailedWorkoutResponse for next workout request
                                                                    module.exports.getFailedWorkoutResponse(req, workoutRequestList, 0, failedWorkoutRequestsList, function (failedWorkoutRequestsList) {
                                                                        //update database for club testing status
                                                                        module.exports.updateClubWorkoutTestStatus(clubid, failedWorkoutRequestsList, function () {
                                                                            //get admin user email id
                                                                            module.exports.getAdminUserEmailId(req, function (email) {
                                                                                //Send email 
                                                                                module.exports.sendEmailForFailedWorkoutResponse(req, clubid, email, workoutRequestList, failedWorkoutRequestsList);
                                                                                //Send response to service
                                                                                if (!Utilities.isEmptyList(failedWorkoutRequestsList)) {
                                                                                    res.json(failedWorkoutRequestsList);
                                                                                } else {
                                                                                    res.json({"message": "No error found in generated workouts :-)"});
                                                                                }
                                                                            });
                                                                        });
                                                                    });

                                                                } else {
                                                                    req.log.error({err: err}, 'Unable to list all durationpreferences data.');
                                                                    res.json({err: "Unable to list all durationpreferences data."});
                                                                }

                                                            });


                                                        } else {
                                                            req.log.error({err: err}, 'Unable to list all durationpreferences data.');
                                                            res.json({err: "Unable to list all durationpreferences data."});
                                                        }

                                                    });

                                                } else {
                                                    req.log.error({err: err}, 'Unable to list all experiences data.');
                                                    res.json({err: "Unable to list all experiences data."});
                                                }

                                            });

                                        } else {
                                            req.log.error({err: err}, 'Unable to list all genders data.');
                                            res.json({err: "Unable to list all genders data."});
                                        }

                                    });

                                } else {
                                    req.log.error({err: err}, 'Unable to list all scheduleconfigfrequencies data.');
                                    res.json({err: "Unable to list all scheduleconfigfrequencies data."});
                                }

                            });
                        } else {
                            req.log.error({err: err}, 'Unable to list all goals data.');
                            res.json({err: "Unable to list all goals data."});
                        }

                    });
                } else {
                    req.log.error({err: err}, 'Unable to list all users data.');
                    res.json({err: "Unable to list all users data."});
                }

            });
        });
    }
};
```

I do see a real callback hell problem here. However I am not sure how to solve this problem. Due to callback chain, till this thread doesn't finish processing, server is not serving other thread and because of that other apps stopped working.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I am probably not an expert on this subject joy but I can share what I have learned recently.

Yes, you are right and your problem seems understandable. What you and I want to achieve is part of scaling an application for bigger mass.

To utilize the multiple cores despite our node.js being a single core application we need to refactor it using clusters module.

Then comes the part where we may need to use load balancing techniques spiced up with proxy servers.

I was reading extensively on same subject and I found this blog post to be very useful - http://cjihrig.com/blog/scaling-node-js-applications/

I agree that this post may not be that useful but I'm sharing what I have learned in recent days.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the above code is that it isn't written in an async style.  During the 30 minutes or so that it runs, its running a single function which doesn't return until the 30 minutes of work is complete.  If you split the work into smaller units via functions that schedule each other via `$timeout` then this will give the node.js scheduler a chance to run other functions to handle other requests.

Comment: How can I structure my code here? Every task is dependent on others task therefore I have added it as callback fashion. Can you please share any example? or any hint?